# Transaction Management in Orient DB

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases

I am using using below logic to start the transaction in Orient DB.
    `graphFactory.getDatabase().begin(type);`
What I am observing is if the transaction is not closed inside the method, It is auto available to other method, Which seems like leak to me. I will try to explain the scenario below:

```
 public <T> void addVertexToDB(T data){
    graphFactory.getDatabase().begin(OTransaction.TXTYPE.OPTIMISTIC);
    //logic for fetching data and adding vertex
    //I am neither calling rollback nor commit here
    }
```

I have another method like update

```
public <T> void updateVertexToDB(T data){
    //not starting the transaction explicitly and doing some write operation
    //logic for fetching data and adding vertex
    //I am neither calling rollback nor commit here
    }
```

The graph factory has below property set

```
graphFactory.setAutoStartTx(false);
graphFactory.setRequireTransaction(true);
```

Expectation: updateVertexToDB should throw `OTransactionException e` 
current Behavior: it gets the transcation started by save and working fine.

So just wanted to know How I can achieve the behavior that if a method is not starting transcation and trying to write to DB, It must throw `OTransactionException e` until it is not nested inside a method already running transaction.

Answer (score 1):

What's graphFactory? The name is misleading. It doesn't look like a `OrientGraphFactory`, but rather a OrientGraph object, right?

Anyway, with the call `graphFactory.getDatabase().begin(OTransaction.TXTYPE.OPTIMISTIC);` you're bypassing the GraphAPI. If you use with Graph API the behaviour should be the expected one. Try calling `graphFactory.begin();`

Comment: OrientGraphFactory does not have any exposed method called begin();

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the way I was verifying the transaction. I have written those two method test inside same Junit class, which was being run by same same thread(main). Hence transaction was shared.
I cross verified that by spawning new thread in the second method and try to write to database and it thrown the exception.